# Bubble Sort so that all numbers ending in the digit 5 comes in ascending order

Tags: c, algorithm, bubble-sort

I am trying to implement a bubblesort of an array of integers so that all numbers ending in digit 5 comes first (ascending order), followed by all numbers which do not end in 5 (ascending order).

Before BubbleSort: [5, 1, 23, 45, 65, 89, -85, -76]

After Bubblesort (ending digit 5 (ascending order)):  [-85, 5, 45, 65, -76, 1, 23, 89]

So I do know how to write the standard Bubblesort but I can't wrap my mind around the additional rule (ending in digit 5). Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: why didn't 45 move to front after sorting?

Comment: Raskeshbs - it did, I just made a copying mistake, sorry!

Comment: Do you have any additional requirements/restrictions? For example, does everything need to be done in the original array? If not, a simple although inefficient way would be to process the array to get all the values evenly divisible by 5 and sort them separately, then sort the remaining values, and finally put the two results together.

Comment: James - there are no additional requirements or restrictions

Comment: suggest implementing a bubble sort that considers a 'number&0x05== 0xx05' to come before numbers that do not evaluate to the above expression.  And that expression to take presidence over the actual values.  This would mean more comparisons rather than just one in the normal bubble sort algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that needs to change is the compare code.

Assuming bubble sort code is working and uses a simple compare like:

```
if (a < b) ...
```

Create function as below.  `a%10` will result in values `-9,-8,...,8,9`.  Test when this result is `5` or `-5`.  The below tests when the `|a%10| == 5`.

```
// Return 1 when a should come before b in the array.
int cmp5(int a, int b) {
  int a5 = abs(a%10) == 5;
  int b5 = abs(b%10) == 5;
  // Since a and b are the same "five-ness", do a simple compare
  if (a5 == b5) return a < b;
  if (a5) return 1;
  return 0;
  // Could replace above 2 lines with `return a5;`
}
```

and call

```
 if (cmp5(a,b)) ...
```

Comment: @James Adkison Thanks for the correction about `int b5 = ...`, but the rest of the suggested edit was the opposite intended ordering.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken when this logic will sort them in descending order with all multiples of 5 at the end of the list? I guess it depends on the interpretation of your return value. What should the bubble sort algorithm do when 0 is returned?

Comment: @James Adkison The premises is that unseen code had a sorting order (supposedly ascending) that depending on `(a < b)` and `cmp5(a,b)` replaces that.  Should  `cmp5(a,b)` be of the opposite polarity, OP will certainly use `!cmp5(a,b)` or tailor the code as needed.  Also: it is not a "multiples of 5" issue, but a "numbers ending in the digit 5" issue.  Thanks for the close review

Comment: Yes, thanks for point out my oversight about "ending in 5". I believe I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you know standard bubble sort, good now do the following

1. Take two arrays/vector (the one which you prefer)
2. one for multiples of 5 and other for remaining
3. Now just make standard bubble sort function bubblesort(array[])
4. Filter the inputs to the two arrays
5. After filtering make a call to bubble sort and you are done
6. And put the both results together

Comment: what would be the best way to combine the two arrays?

Comment: You can make array.push () but due to limit of indexes you would face some problems (if array size is too long  )so use of vectors can make this step overcome